# Highchart - how to display 2 graphs with 2 different values in tooltip

Tags: php, jsfiddle

I prepared something for you on jFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jJyXe/1/

I have to different series. I want to display them with two different units. So for temperature it's °C and for brightness its lx. I am not clear how to add this in the tooltip ...

```
pointFormat: '<b>{point.y}</b>',
```

I think that's the point there I can define it? Something like

```
pointFormat: '<b>{point.y}</b> °C' + <b>{point.y}</b> lx',
```

But point.y are both datapoints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works well.. Try it. Just add formatter function in your tooltip. It will give you exact result. The function below,

```
$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({   
        chart: {renderTo: 'container'},
        tooltip: {
           formatter: function() {
               if(this.series.name == 'brightness')
                   var suffix = "lx";
               else
                   var suffix = "°C";
               return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
               this.y +suffix;
           }
        },
     series: [{ name: 'brightness', data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4]}, 
              { name: 'temperature',data: [16.4, 194.1, 95.6]}]    
    });
});
```

Comment: Just one question. my date is like [timestamp,value],[timestamp,value], .... how can i convert timestamp to a date? because when i replace this.series.name with this.x i see just the timestamp

Comment: Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x)

Comment: Sorry I found it with some search